# How to I Fix django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

when I try to create a new instance of an Employee I get an error:

`django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'bio'"`

When I `print` this line  `print(request.data)` within the post method in 'EmployeeAddView` class

I get:

```
<QueryDict: {'joining_date': ['2018-03-04'], 'designation': ['1'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['5AeZ7lFOE2Z5j8cPNNZtygh208Esw65tvf5fzka56nCAj1oUFWCR3fcNHuOok2JK'], 'bio.marital_status': ['1'], 'bio.preferred_language': ['English'], 'tax_id_number': ['333333333ed'], 'bio.birthday': ['2018-03-04'], 'bio.user.first_name': ['Jack'], 'department': ['2'], 'bio.user.last_name': ['Sparrow'], 'bio.phone_number': ['9999999'], 'bio.main_id_type_no': ['459opppp'], 'bio.id_type': ['1'], 'bio.gender': ['1'], 'account_number': ['qwwwwwwww3r3']}>
Internal Server Error: /hr/employee_add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'bio'
```

I have this at `views.py`

```
class EmployeeAddView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class=EmployeeSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        designation = Group.objects.get(id=self.request.data['designation'],)
        department = Group.objects.get(id=self.request.data['department'],) 
        bio = Bio.objects.get(id=self.request.data['bio'],)       
        employee = Employee.objects.create(
            tax_id_number=request.data['tax_id_number'],
            account_number=request.data['account_number'],
            joining_date=request.data['joining_date'],
            designation =designation,
            department =department,
            bio=bio,

            )

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Then I have created a serializer like this:

```
# Nest Bio With User seriializer
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: Define serializer fields here
    bio = BioSerializer()
    #user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        # fields = ['user','tax_id_number','account_number','joining_date','designation','department','gender','marital_status','id_type','birthday','ethnicity','preferred_language','phone_number','em_contact','address']
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can add request body you are trying to post? Does it contain `bio`?

Comment: You don't have any `key` named `bio` in your `request.data`

Comment: you  don't have bio key in request.data. try this-->
`bio = Bio.objects.get(id=self.request.data['bio.id_type'][0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views.py file update your code as below

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    print(request.data)
    designation = Group.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('designation',None),)
    department = Group.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('department', None),) 
    bio = Bio.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('bio', None),)
    if designation and department and bio:
        employee = Employee.objects.create(
        tax_id_number=request.data['tax_id_number'],
        account_number=request.data['account_number'],
        joining_date=request.data['joining_date'],
        designation =designation,
        department =department,
        bio=bio,
        )
```

updating line as bio = Bio.objects.get(id=self.request.data.get('bio', None),) will give you none value if the key is missing or the key has None value, **but It will not give you the MultiValueDictKeyError.**